# Task 'Files' not found in root project

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have Jenkinsfile to deploy my artifact to JFrog Artifactory

```
node() {

def server
def buildInfo
def rtGradle

stage('Clone') {
   ///my gitlab url
}

stage('Artifactory configuration') {
     server = Artifactory.server 'my-server-id'
     rtGradle = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
     rtGradle.tool = 'Gradle 4.6' // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
     rtGradle.deployer repo: 'epm-lstr-hri-maven', server: server
     rtGradle.resolver repo: 'epm-lstr-hri-maven', server: server
     rtGradle.deployer.deployArtifacts = false
     buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
}

  stage ('Build') {
    rtGradle.run rootDir: ".", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'build'
}

stage ('Deploy') {
    rtGradle.run rootDir: ".", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 

'artifactoryPublish', buildInfo: buildInfo
        rtGradle.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
    }

    stage ('Publish build info') {
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
    }
}
```

After running this job exception appears:

```
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] ArtifactoryGradleBuild
[CommonAPIArt] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation\Gradle_4.6\bin\gradle.bat"' --init-script C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/workspace/test_project/CommonAPIArt@tmp/init-artifactory1204060565575984338gradle build -b .\build.gradle && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'Files' not found in root project 'common-api'.
```

What is the **task 'File'** in Gradle? It is absent in my project, how I can deploy artifacts using pipline?

Comment: It's probably because of the spaces in "Program Files (x86)" it's seeing Files as a new parameter...  Not on Windows, so not sure what you need to do here to escape the space...

Comment: @tim_yates Thank you so much!!! I've just moved a folder with Jenkins on the top level, and It works!!!

Comment: No worries, post that as an answer, it might help people in the future with the same problem :-)